# asp.net mvc razor string with double quotes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I am trying to use a string with double quotes but unable to get it work

```
@{
    string disableMessage = "";
    var disableAttr = "";
    if (ViewBag.IsApplicable)
    {
        disableMessage = "You dont have permission to add new Item.";
        disableAttr = "class=" + "disableItem" +" title="+"\""+ disableMessage +"\"";
    }

}
```

expected: disableAttr as

```
class=disableItem title="You dont have permission to add new demand."
```

I got struck at getting double quotes for title attribute.

Comment: disableAttr = "class=disableItem title=\""+ disableMessage + "\"";

Comment: If you're trying to use it as HTML, then it won't work. Although in C# you can have escaped double quotes, you cant have that in HTML. You need to use `'` apostrophes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not deal with the two attributes separately:

```
@{
    string disableTitle = null;
    string disableClass = null;
    if (ViewBag.IsApplicable)
    {
        disableTitle = "You dont have permission to add new Item.";
        disableClass = "disableItem";
    }
}

<div class="@disableClass" title="@disableTitle">Content</div>
```

Note that Razor V2 (in MVC4+) has a "conditional attribute" feature. When an attribute value is null, then Razor won't output anything at all for the attribute. So in the example above, if `ViewBag.IsApplicable` is `false`, the output will be:

```
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: How can I manage the below scenario? 

<div id="btnNewDemand" 
        @(disableMessage != null ? ( "class=@disableClass" + "title=@disableTitle") : "") >

Comment: @Chandana `<div id="foo" @if(condition) { <text>attrib1="@value1" attrib2="@value2"</text> }>` would deal with quotes and escaping nicely, but I think using the conditional attributes feature would give a more readable layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ross's answer is much more elegant. However, keeping the line of your original code, you could do the following:

```
disableAttr = "class='disableItem'" +" title='"+ disableMessage +"'";
```

This will render the following text inside `disableAttr`:

```
class='disableItem' title='your_message_here';
```

Comment: If you want to use double quotes, you can also use string.format(@" class=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\" ", "disableItem", "some message")

Comment: @dcinzona, sure you can. But depending on the HTML, you could end up with invalid characters. Check this for example, using double quotes: `title="Your message is: "this won't work""`. How would that play with your markup?

Comment: Escape the title before setting it. This will be the case regardless of the method used.

Comment: @dcinzona, I'm afraid you're still not getting my point. Forget for a moment about C# and just focus on HTML. The example in my comment is generated using is the exact HTML markup generated by escaping double quotes, but is _invalid HTML_. I'm not arguing about **not** using escaping, but about the benefits of using both _double quotes_ and _apostrophes_ when generating HTML (and JavaScript, for that matter).

Comment: No matter what, you're going to want to escape the message that is stored as an attribute to an HTML element, regardless of the enclosure.  If the message contains single quotes (or apostrophes, as some like to call them ;) ), then you will have broken HTML again.  My point was using string.format to create the string. For me, string.format is syntactically easier to read as a developer than something = "\'something else\'" + thisOtherThing + '\"other message\"'

Comment: By the way, your example title="Your message is: "this won't work"" won't work with apostrophe enclosures either.  title='Your message is: "this won' <======broken